# How to avoid infinite loop when nesting api resources in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two models: `Company` and `Representative`. Representative belongsTo Company, Company hasMany Representative.

Also I have two corresponding resources.

**Company resource**:

```php
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->id,
            'title'       => $this->title,   
            'representatives' => RepresentativeResource::collection($this->representatives)
        ];
    }
```

**Representative resource**:

```php
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'company' => $this->company ? new CompanyResource($this->company) : null
        ];
    }
```

What I want to accomplish is when I get companies I want to get theirs representatives. When I get representative I want to get information about company.

What happens is infinite loop: their include each other infinitely.

So, how could it be fixed?

Comment: First you have to define the business logic. What data do you need and why? Then comes the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to use `whenLoaded`? It's documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships) and I think it fits your needs.

With your code, you shoud have something like this:

```php
class CompanyResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,   
            'representatives' => RepresentativeResource::collection(
                $this->whenLoaded('representatives')
            )
        ];
    } 
}
```

---

```php
class RepresentativeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'company' => new CompanyResource(
                $this->whenLoaded('company')
            )
        ];
    } 
}
```

In your controller then, you'll have to load the relationship with your model.

```php
new RepresentativeResource(Representative::with('company')->first());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The only thing which I couldn't get is that if I retrieve a company, it returns its representatives and each representative contains company (even though I load companies in my controller using ->with('representatives'), not ->with('representatives.company')). So I get a lot of data which is not used (since I already know what company I'm working with)

Comment: Other solution without `$this->whenLoaded`?? @pellul

Comment: @francisco Alas, I didn't have the opportunity to use Laravel for years now. It looks like it's still the way to do though. It's in the current version's documentation under [Eloquent resources - Conditional relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships). Do you have any reason not to use it?

Comment: @pellul `->whenLoaded` works fine as it is with the curent code, but my boss don't want it, just that reason why I need to change..